# open chrome with local file in android

Tags: android

I am trying to launch chrome from my app with a local file.html 
here is my code:

```
   String url2 = "file:///"
        + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
        + File.separator + "new folder"+ "/index.html";
    url2  = url2 .replaceAll(" ", "%20");
    Uri uri2 = Uri.parse(url2 );   
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri2);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setPackage("com.android.chrome");

    try {
      startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        intent.setPackage(null);
      startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: `by paste url in chrome it works fine`. Thank you for that info. I knew that Chrome is not in the list for intents to show local html files. I always thougth that Chrome would not load content from file. But it does aparently.    For the rest it is strange that even if you mention chrome it still does not work.

Comment: it does not appear in browser list when trying to open html file , but when pasting url it opens  thanks to @shhp answer it works now

Comment: `it does not appear in browser list when trying to open html file`. Indeed. But your info openend my eyes. So i made a little `ChromeMate` app which comes in the list instead. When chosen ChromeMate starts Chrome with the supplied file-url (in the way @shhp suggested).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Uri uri2 = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
    + File.separator + "new folder"+ "/index.html"));
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri2);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setClassName("com.android.chrome", "com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main");

try {
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    try {
        intent.setPackage(null);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

Comment: This works. Chrome is started. I tested this on about ten devices. Mostly Chrome could not open the page and often it said it did not have the rights. I think that Chrome -like any app- needs the EXTERNAL_READ permission. But that those were not requested. By lack of that it cannot open the html file.

Comment: `startActivity(intent);`. |The second one needs another try-catch in case Chrome is not installed. Or what was the reason? (I forgot due through those many devices).

Comment: @greenapps is your html file stored in sd card?

Comment: In external memory always.